# Tables shifting to the right using form inputs

Tags: html, forms, input, html-table

I've been searching for help on this and haven't found anything that has worked yet.  I have a webpage which includes HTML, PHP, Javascript and CSS. It's really basic.  It's has images in tables for the background and rollovers and I have a form with two inputs. It looks fine in Firefox and OK in IE but in google chrome it shifts images to the right.  This happened with IE also and I was able to make it work by making the size smaller:

```
<td> <input size="19" name="email" type="text" ><br>
```

size="19" seemed to work (but not perfectly).  In chrome it shifts the tables to the right.

Here's the code (please go easy on me):

```
<?php 
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';
sec_session_start();
if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {
    $logged = 'in';} else {
    $logged = 'out';}
?>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/mystyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/sha512.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/forms.js"></script> 
    <title>login</title>
  </head>
  <body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" style="    background-color: white;" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">

    <form action="includes/process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">
      <table  class="center" id="Table_01" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="601" width="720"
      style="table-layout:auto" >
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="9"> <img src="images/login_01.gif" alt="" height="120" width="720"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> <img src="images/login_02.gif" alt="" height="29" width="67"></td>
            <td> <a href="register.php" target="_self"> <img src="images/login_register.gif"
                  alt="register" border="0" height="29" width="107"></a></td>
            <td colspan="5"> <img src="images/login_04.gif" alt="" height="29" width="364"></td>
            <td> <a href="reset.php" target="_self"> <img src="images/login_reset.gif"
                  alt="reset_password" border="0" height="29" width="121"></a></td>
            <td> <img src="images/login_06.gif" alt="" height="29" width="61"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="9"> <img src="images/login_07.gif" alt="" height="102" width="720"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3"> <img src="images/login_08.gif" alt="" height="22" width="293"></td>
            <!-- EMAIL FORM -->
            <td> <input size="19" name="email" type="text" ><br>
            </td>
            <td colspan="5"> <img src="images/login_10.gif" alt="" height="22" width="285"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="9"> <img src="images/login_11.gif" alt="" height="56" width="720"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3"> <img src="images/login_12.gif" alt="" height="22" width="293"></td>
            <!-- PASSWORD FORM -->
            <td> <input size="19" type="password" name="password" id="password"  /></td>
            <td> <img src="images/login_14.gif" alt="" height="22" width="23"></td>
            <td> <INPUT TYPE="image" SRC="images/login_submit.gif" WIDTH="55"  HEIGHT="22" 
              BORDER="0" ALT="Submit" value="Login" onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);">           
              </td>
            <td colspan="3"> <img src="images/login_16.gif" alt="" height="22" width="207"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="9"> <img src="images/login_17.gif" alt="" height="249" width="720"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> <img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" height="1" width="67"></td>
            <td> <img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" height="1" width="107"></td>
            <td> <img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" height="1" width="119"></td>
            <td> <img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" height="1" width="142"></td>
            <td> <img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" height="1" width="23"></td>
            <td> <img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" height="1" width="55"></td>
            <td> <img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" height="1" width="25"></td>
            <td> <img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" height="1" width="121"></td>
            <td> <img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" height="1" width="61"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>


<?php
    if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
    echo '<p class="error">Error Logging In!</p>';
    }
?> 

  </body>
</html>
```

What can I do to make this page show correctly in IE Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: Have you tried setting padding and margin for img to 0, and border to none?

Comment: No not for img.  I will try that now.  Where should I do this in CSS or in the <img>?

Comment: It doesn't really matter, but I think CSS is better practice.

Comment: Put in your css -> <code> img {margin:0} </code> tip: it will affect all your images in your pages that has attached css for style.

Comment: Hmm. Can you setup a JSFiddle to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was able to fix this by adding:

 form { 
 margin:  0px;
 border:  0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

input {
   margin:  0px;
 border:  0px;
 padding:  0px;
} 

to my .css file.  Now it looks fine in each browser!  :D